# TypeError 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner at python and I have no idea how to fix this. Please help.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Priscilla\Desktop\CMPT Assn #3\page.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
TypeError: 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Python script:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage

# print HTTP/HTML header stuff
print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Order Form</title>
</head><body>
"""

# print HTML body using form data
print "<h1>Kintoro Japanese Bar &amp; Restaurant</h1>"
print "<h2>Customer Reciept</h2>"
print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Customer Email Address:", form["custEmail"].value, "</p>"
print "<h2>Customer Address:</h2>"
print "<p>Street:", form["custAdd"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>City:", form["custCity"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Province:", form["custProv"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Postal Code:", form["custPostal"].value, "</p>"
print "<h2>Payment Information:</h2>"
print "<p>Card Type:", form["type1"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Card Number: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-", form["four4"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Expiry Date:", form["expDate"].value, "</p>"
```

Comment: Instead of doing `print`s, consider using a simple templating engine, e.g. [tempita](http://pythonpaste.org/tempita/) available via `easy_install` or `pip`. Better yet, consider using a simple web framework like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [web.py](http://webpy.org/) and don't access raw form storage again.

Comment: Don't change your question whenever a new error arises.  Stick to one problem per question.

Answer (score 2):

`form = cgi.FieldStorage` assigns the class `FieldStorage` itself to `form`.  You want to assign an instance of `FieldStorage` instead:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did forget the brackets, but after i put it in, this error arose:

  File "C:\Users\Priscilla\Desktop\CMPT Assn #3\page.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 540, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError, key
KeyError: 'custName'

Comment: @user3895456: I think that's because you need to run the script as a CGI script (i.e., on a webserver) to which you POST a form with fields "custName" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate `FieldStorage`.

What you do: `form = cgi.FieldStorage`. This makes `form` equal to the class `cgi.FieldStorage`. The class knows nothing about your current request.

What you mean: `form = cgi.FieldStorage()`. This creates a new instance associated with the current request.

Comment: Another error arose after I put in the brackets:

  File "C:\Users\Priscilla\Desktop\CMPT Assn #3\page.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 540, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError, key
KeyError: 'custName'

Comment: `KeyError` means that form['custName'] does not exist. Try printing `form.keys()` somewhere (e.g in the log) and see what is actually passed.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the `[]` operator in python calls the `__getitem__(key)` method of the object. It seems that in your case that method was not defined for the class of which `form` is an instance.

To fix this, you will need to define the method and its behavior in the relevant class.

For more information, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Comment: The `FieldStorage` class is defined by [`cgi`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html), a standard Python module.  The documentation indicates that subscripting should work, and [`__getitem__` is explicitly defined in the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cgi.py#l532).